# Arduino does not see data from nodemcu

Tags: arduino-nano, nodemcu

I’m trying to send data from a NodeMCU to an Arduino nano.

If I try to send data with one second delay - all working fine.

But if I try to send without delay or with a delay less than one second, then arduino sees data but nothing not does.

Arduino nano sketch:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo servo1; 

int servo = 6; 
int engine = 5; 

void setup() { 
Serial.begin(9600); 
analogWrite(servo, 67); 
servo1.attach(8); 
} 

void loop() { 
if (Serial.available()) { 
String model = Serial.readStringUntil(':'); 
i 

f (model.equals("engine")){ 
String value = Serial.readStringUntil('c'); 
int power = value.toInt(); 
analogWrite(engine, power); 
} 
if (model.equals("servo")){ 
String value_servo = Serial.readStringUntil('c'); 
int power_servo = value_servo.toInt(); 
servo1.write(power_servo); 
} 
} 
}
```

NodeMCU sketch:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> 
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h> 
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h> 

const char* ssid = "my_wifi_ssid"; 
const char* password = "my_wifi_password"; 

ESP8266WebServer server(80); 


void get_vars(){ 
if (server.argName(0) == "engine"){ 
server.send(200, "text/plain", "Reading engine. Value: "+server.arg(0)); 
Serial.println("engine:"+server.arg(0)+"c"); 
} 
if (server.argName(0) == "servo"){ 
server.send(200, "text/plain", "Reading engine. Value: "+server.arg(0)); 
Serial.println("servo:"+server.arg(0)+"c"); 
} 
} 

void setup(void){ 
main_stuff(); 
} 

void loop(void){ 
server.handleClient(); 
} 


void main_stuff(){ 
Serial.begin(9600); 
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); 
WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 
Serial.println(""); 

// Wait for connection 
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
delay(100); 
Serial.print("."); 
} 
Serial.println(""); 
Serial.print("Connected to "); 
Serial.println(ssid); 
Serial.print("IP address: "); 
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); 

if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) { 
Serial.println("MDNS responder started"); 
} 

server.onNotFound(get_vars); 

server.begin(); 
Serial.println("HTTP server started"); 

}
```

Comment: In the Arduino IDE, press "Ctrl" + "T" that will make your code easier to read.

Comment: What does this mean "But if i try to send without delay or delay < one second, then arduino sees data but nothing not does.", could you elaborate?

Comment: @MatsK, when the NodeMcu sends something to the Arduino - the built-in LED on it blinks

Comment: `nothing not does` is a double negative ... it means `something does` .... it is unclear what you mean by that statement

Answer (score 1):

the newline characters from println (\r\n) stay in the serial input buffer and you read them with `Serial.readStringUntil(':');`. then the string is not "servo" but "\r\nservo"

if you wait one second with sending, the the \r\n are discarded because the readStringUntil times out one second after reading them

Comment: And how to fix this?

Comment: Thank you very much! All work fine. I'am just change "Serial.println" to "Serial.print"